# IBM Worklight - Sending HTTP POST request from the client side

Tags: http, post, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have an application which needs to send an HTTP POST request from the client side to a server every half an hour. The server would then update a database with the parameters sent by the client. My question is how do I initiate a HTTP Post request to the server from the client through Worklight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by reading the server-side development section of the IBM Worklight Getting Started page:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development

Specifically, these modules:

- [HTTP adapter – Communicating with HTTP back-end systems](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf)
- [Invoking adapter procedures from client applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_06_Invoking_adapter_procedures_from_client_applications.pdf)

Each module has an exercise as well as a sample application.

There is more information in the [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adapters? Namely an http adapter.